# How to configure apache with proxy_mod for domains redirect

Tags: apache, apache2, mod-proxy

I have a server with only one IP adress but a lot of domain (and sub-doman) but every domain have dedicated virtual machine on my Host Server.

I try to use mod_proxy for ProxyPass and Reverse request and, in apache conf i make it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAlias mydomain.domain.com
        ProxyRequests Off
        <Proxy />
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
                ProxyPass http://192.168.1.8/
                ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.1.8/
        </Proxy>
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ProxyRequests Off
        ServerAlias domain.domain2.org
        ServerAlias subdomanin.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

In this conf:

```
domain.domain1.com -> go to 192.168.1.8
subdomanin.domain1.com and another domain  -> go to document root.
```

With ProxyRequests On and "Allow from All" (this conf), apache is an openproxy... 
With this config (and ProxyRequest Off), if someone request "www.google.it" with proxy mydomain.domain.com he don't have google but server redirect it to myNumericIp

What is right config for do if http://mydomain.domain.com/some request are redirect to myNumericIp with url http://my.Numeric.Ip/some otherwhise proxy don't response anything).

I try this:

```
<Proxy http://mydomain.domain.com/>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        ProxyPass http://192.168.1.8/
        ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.1.8/
</Proxy>
```

Or this:

```
<Proxy />
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        ProxyPass http://192.168.1.8/
        ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.1.8/
</Proxy>
<Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
</Proxy>
```

But don't work...

Answer (score 0):

Using the following steps:

**1) Update virtual file:-**

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
> ServerAdmin admin@test.com
> ServerName mysite.com
> ServerAlias www.mysite.com   ProxyRequests Off Order deny,allow Allow from all  <Location />
>     ProxyPass http:// mysite.com:8000/
>     ProxyPassReverse http:// mysite.com:8000/
> </Location>
> ```

**2) Enabling Necessary Apache Modules**

To enable these four modules, execute the following commands in succession.

> sudo a2enmod proxy
>
> sudo a2enmod proxy_http
>
> sudo a2enmod proxy_balancer
>
> sudo a2enmod lbmethod_byrequests

**3) To put these changes into effect, restart Apache.**

> sudo systemctl restart apache2